# Issues using Spring's DomainClassConverter in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Spring's DomainClassConverter feature with my Spring MVC project. (I have only very basic knowledge of Spring MVC and Spring, apologies in advance for any naive question here).

From the [API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core.web):

```
The DomainClassConverter allows you to use domain types in your Spring MVC controller 
method signatures directly, so that you don't have to manually lookup the instances via 
the repository: (PS: Example 1.20)
```

What I understood from the above is that I don't have to write a finder method and the Spring supplies the `User` object. So these are the steps I did:

Included the below line of XML in `applicationcontext.xml`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" />
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
<property name="converters">
    <list>
        <bean class="com.rl.userservice.controller.UserConverter"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

Included this dependency in my `pom.xml` per the [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) doc:

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
>         <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

My controller looks like the below:

> ```
> @Controller
> @RequestMapping(value = "/api/newuser")
> public class NewUserServiceController {
>       @Autowired
>   NewUserRepository newUserRepository;
>
>   @RequestMapping("/{id}")
>     public String showUserForm(@PathVariable("id") NewUser newUser, Model model) {
>
>       model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);
>       return "userForm";
>     } 
> }
> ```

Repository is like this:

> ```
> @Repository
> public interface NewUserRepository extends JpaRepository<NewUser, Integer> {
> }
> ```

This is my converter service:

```
final class UserConverter implements Converter<Integer, NewUser> {
    NewUserRepository newUserRepository;

    public NewUser convert(Integer username) {
        return newUserRepository.findOne(username);
    } 
}
```

When I run the program tomcat starts successful, but when accessing the URL *localhost:8080/userservice/api/newuser/1* I get the below exception:

```
type Exception report
    message
    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
    exception
    org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'com.mpp.userservice.domain.NewUser'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type  
[java.lang.String] to required type
[com.mpp.userservice.domain.NewUser]: no matching editors or
conversion strategy found
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:71)
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
      org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:595)
      org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:101)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

    root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
[com.mpp.userservice.domain.NewUser]: no matching editors or
conversion strategy found
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
      org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
      org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:595)
      org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:101)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
      org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.
    mpp.
```

Though not the best code, here's my controller:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ModelMap> getUserTypeJSON(@PathVariable("userID" String userID, HttpServletResponse response)  { 
    UserType UserType = UserTypeRepository.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("Name",UserType.getName());  
    ...
}
```

There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347284/conversionservice-in-spring) that I referenced, but this is using custom converter but does not seem to be using the domain converter service. Please advise. Is this the way to go if I want to reduce boilerplate code of writing CRUD operations? What is the real benefit of this `DomainClassConverter` when I can get the data in in the other way?

**Updated per Oliver Gierke suggestion - still does not work, same error**

The document describes:

> ```
> <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
> <bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
>   <constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
> </bean>
> ```

So I updated my `applicationcontext.xml` as below, but the same issue:

> ```
>     <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
>
>   <bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
>     <constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
>   </bean>
>
>     <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
>     <property name="converters">
>         <list>
>           <bean class="com.rl.userservice.controller.UserConverter"/>
>         </list>
>     </property>
>   </bean>
> ```

Still the same issue.

**Update:** DomainClassConverter works with Java Config, but not the XML way (at least experimented with a lot of combinations suggested here and else where on the internet). Just for the others who might be interested and get some useful info here's the code used.

*pom.xml (Might require clean-up)*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

*The controller file (Might require clean-up)*

```
@RequestMapping("/domain/{id}")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ModelMap> showDomainUserForm(@PathVariable("id") User userMatch, HttpServletResponse response) {

  // some code omitted…  

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();        
    model.addAttribute("DOMAIN-MAP","Domain Controller Service");
    model.addAttribute("Name",userMatch.getName());
    model.addAttribute("Phone",userMatch.getPhone());                                           

    // some code omitted…


  }
```

*The Java Config file assembled using examples from [resource1](http://www.joshlong.com/jl/blogPost/simplified_web_configuration_with_spring.html) and [resource2](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-customizing.html).
(Might require clean-up)*

```
package com.rl.userservice.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter;
import org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
     @Bean
     public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
      RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
      handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
      handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
      return handlerMapping;
     } 


     @Bean
     public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter() {
         return new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(mvcConversionService());
     }

     @Override
     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
         configurer.enable();
     }

}
```

*Add the below bean definition in the applicationContext.xml*

```
<bean class="com.rl.userservice.controller.WebConfig"/>
```

Comment: What is `applicationcontext.xml` is it your dispatcher servlet context? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring MVC tag and converters are likely to be declared in the context which is used by dispatcher servlet - not the root application web app context.

Comment: Don't define your own conversion service (or custom UserConverter). Remove your `conversionService` bean definition!

Comment: @Pavel can you elaborate? In this case I think the conversion service is in the wrong context, so it's shadowed by the one in dispatcher servlet, but in general there is nothing wrong with explicit declaration of custom beans.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov There is nothing wrong with declaring custom beans. However the custom `UserConverter` is duplicating what `DomainClassConverter` should be doing and its presence makes the issue a bit more complex. As per the `conversionService`, that is where I was a bit too rash... there is definitelly one needed.

Comment: For some reason the XML has an issue. I tried the same with Java Config and the DomainClassConverter worked perfectly fine.

Comment: you can check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459036/how-can-i-use-a-custom-id-conversion-with-domainclassconverter/35128628#35128628

Answer (score 1):

A URL is a `String`, so `{id}` is a `String` too. Therefore your service must be able to convert a `String` to `NewUser`, not an `Integer` as yours does.

Comment: Is that comment for UserConverter class? Even with this the error is the same:
public NewUser convert(String username) {
    return newUserRepository.findOne(Integer.parseInt(username));
} 
}

Comment: @oneworld Not sure if it's necessary, but I'm using the `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`, not the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [relevant section of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e1111) to find out about the correct way to configure the `DomainClassConverter`.

Comment: I tried per the solution, but doesn't work. I also tried your other solutions here - https://jira.springsource.org/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATACMNS-133/DATACMNS-133.html
Is there still issues with DomainClassConverter? The latest docs are slightly different too http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core.web

Comment: I searched through the internet and find no good working sample of code. Every site has its own way of doing but only provides piecemeal information. Is there any sample projects that I could completely reference?

Comment: Is this issue still hovering? http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/113584-help-with-domainclassconverter-configuration

Answer (score 0):

The [ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/repositories.html) says

> Currently the repository has to implement CrudRepository to be
>   eligible to be discovered for conversion.

Shouldn't that be the reason?

Comment: JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository which in turn extends CrudRepository, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

This configuration sets up a custom conversion service and passes it to annotation scanning mechanism that detects and sets up the controllers:

```
<bean name="conversionService" class="rest.gateway.services.MyConversionService"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

And this is the code for the custom controller, customer being a domain class like User:

```
public class MyConversionService extends DefaultConversionService {

    public MyConversionService() {
        super();
        addConverter(String.class, Customer.class, new Converter<String, Customer>() {
            @Override
            public Customer convert(String source) {
                return new Customer("123456","Doe","John");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Have a try with this because this is working for version 2.0.0.M1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: this is based in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e1111, i've used it and can confirm that it's working

Comment: Do I really need to write a custom converter for a domain converter class? Is it not deflating the purpose?