# Java | API to get protocol://domain.port from URL

Tags: java

I have got URL as referrer and want to get protocol and domain from it.

For example: If URL is `https://test.domain.com/a/b/c.html?test=hello` then output needs to be `https://test.domain.com`. I have gone through `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html` and I can't seems to find any method that can directly do so.

---

I am not using Spring, so can't use Sprint classes (if any).

---

Guys I can write custom login to get port, domain and protocol from URL, but looking for API which already has this implemented and can minimize my time in testing various scenarios.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ Get domain name from given url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url)

Comment: Look for [java.net.Url](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Comment: URL info might helpyou out. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: @rupesh please check edited link

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Same who given right to you comment :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Sorry brother i put wrong url that time so edited it May be due to Copy-Paste issue.

Comment: thanks @SubodhJoshi, but as I said I am looking for API's like URL or URI that can do so.

Comment: @Rupesh then please change the question title it will make clear picture

Comment: done, as asked. If it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues using Spring's DomainClassConverter in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695180/issues-using-springs-domainclassconverter-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Please check this http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html is it will help you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a new [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object using your `String` value and call [`getHost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost--) or any other method on it, like so:

```
URL url = new URL("https://test.domain.com/a/b/c.html?test=hello");
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String host = url.getHost();
int port = url.getPort();

// if the port is not explicitly specified in the input, it will be -1.
if (port == -1) {
    return String.format("%s://%s", protocol, host);
} else {
    return String.format("%s://%s:%d", protocol, host, port);
}
```

Comment: this will not work if url is `https://test.domain.com:80/a/b/c.html?test=hello` the output should be `https://test.domain.com:80`. I can write these logic but looking for tried and tested API

Comment: port check is not needed, getAuthority gives domain and port

Comment: you must change if condition : if (port == -1)

Comment: Worked for me. But instead of this multi line approach, I prefer getAuthority() which does the same job in single line.

Answer (score 23):

To elaborate on what @Rupesh mentioned in @mthmulders answer,

`getAuthority()` gives both domain and port. So you just concatenate it with `getProtocol()` as prefix:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://test.domain.com/a/b/c.html?test=hello");
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String authority = url.getAuthority();
return String.format("%s://%s", protocol, authority);
```

Comment: If someone like me just want the URL without host name and port then use `url.getPath()`

Answer (score -1):

getAuthority() returns the host along with the port but getHost() returns only the host name. So if URL is "https://www.hello.world.com:80/x/y/z.html?test=hello", then getAuthority() return www.hello.world.com:80 while getHost() returns www.hello.world.com

**Example**

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.hello.world.com:80/x/y/z.html?test=hello");
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String host = url.getHost();
int port = url.getPort();
String authority = url.getAuthority();

System.out.println("Host "+host);   // www.hello.world.com
System.out.println("authority "+authority);   // www.hello.world.com:80

//Determining Protocol plus host plus port (if any) url using Authority (simple single line step)
System.out.println("ProtocolHostPortURL:: "+ String.format("%s://%s", protocol, authority));

//Determining Protocol plus host plus port (if any) url using Authority (multi line step)
//If the port is not explicitly specified in the input, it will be -1.
if (port == -1) {
    System.out.println("ProtocolHostURL1:: "+ String.format("%s://%s", protocol, host));        
} else {
    System.out.println("ProtocolHostPortURL2:: "+ String.format("%s://%s:%d", protocol, host, port));    
}
```