# Spring 3 MVC error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available

Tags: spring-mvc

I know this issue might have been addressed elsewhere but I'm unable to find a satisfactory solution to my problem. Btw, I'm working with spring 3.0.2

Login.jsp

```
<form:form id="_LoginForm" name="LoginForm" modelAttribute="user" action="login" method="POST">
    <form:input path="username" value=""/>
    <form:input path="password" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("recd request");
    return null;
}
```

When I try to access the login.jsp page, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335432/modelattribute-in-a-method

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide your *RequestMethod.GET* method in the controller?
Just want to make sure you are adding the modelAttribute in the *GET* method as well.

Comment: Are suggesting to add a sort of setup method which puts the "user" attribute into the model map and then redirect to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

I added the the following method to make this work, though I feel there must be a better way to get this working without having to write a setup method everytime.

applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
```

index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="index.action"/>
```

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="index.action", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupLogin(Map<String, Object> modelMap) {        
    modelMap.put("user", new User());
    return "Login";
}
```