# Creating a form in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple contact form in my spring project, which is meant to access a backing object, but I get this error

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'indexBacking' available as request attribute"

My form looks like this:

```
<form:form action="index.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" commandName="indexBacking" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <form:label path="personName">Name</form:label>
    <form:input id="personName" path="personName" autocomplete="false" /><br />
    <form:label path="personEmail">Email</form:label>
    <form:input id="personEmail" path="personEmail" autocomplete="false" /><br />
    <form:label path="personComments">Your Comments</form:label>
    <form:input id="personComments" path="personComments" autocomplete="false" /><br />
    <input type="submit" alt="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Which is meant to access my controller and save the fields "personName", "personEmail" and "personComments" into my backing object called "indexBacking".

My controller method that I am trying to access is here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = PAGE_NAME, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleContactForm(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("indexBacking") IndexBacking bo, BindingResult result) {  
    return MODEL_NAME;
}
```

But I am not sure hot it links with the backing object. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very simple, I was just being an idiot. I saw a colleague of mine working on a form and assumed a few of his classes were part of Spring as default. All I had to do was handle the received data at the other end properly (by calling the appropriate methods in the controller) and it worked fine.

Thanks for your help chaps - credit to @nobeh for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `modelAttribute="indexBacking"` on `form:form` instead of `commandName="indexBacking"`.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335572/248082); it might have useful information for your case.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet the prepares the form and displays on the controller's side?

Comment: Isn't that what I posted above? I don't think I have any other related bits of code =P What are you expecting to see?

Comment: When you need to view the form page what URL do you use? Usually, form processing involves a GET request that prepare the form then display it. Then the second step which is submitting data using POST and then process the result. So based on what you've posted, I do not see the complete cycle.

Comment: Silly me! I was being a bit of a numpty (see my answer), thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Sorry for such a late reply.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your controller! 
The following may help you much for your request [Check This](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-annotation-controller-1.html)

Comment: That is what I am doing isn't it? My form is directed towards "indexBacking" and I am accepting it into the method within the controller?